# In mongo, is there a way to use update $setOnInsert and $max together?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to write an update where it would set an object as a value for a key if it does not already exist. If it does exist, I'd like to only update a specific field if the new value is greater than the existing value.

Here is an example of what I'm attempting to do:

```
    ...
    updateOne: {
        filter: {
            _id: name,
        },
        update: {
            $setOnInsert: {
                _id: name,
                value: { ace: true, bay: uniqueID },
            },
            $max: {
                'value.bay': uniqueID,
            },
        },
        upsert: true,
    },
    ...
```

Where `name` and `uniqueID` are both params sent to the function.

If `_id: name` does not exist yet, I'd like to add the object specified by my `$setOnInsert`.

If `_id: name` exists, I'd like to update the `value.bay` field with the new `uniqueID` only if the new value is greater. Specified by my `$max`.

If `_id: name` exists and the new `uniqueID` is NOT greater than previous existing `uniqueID`, then I don't want any change to occur.

I'm wondering if this type of operation is possible in a single query. Any help is appreciated!

Also to add, the current issue I'm facing is if `_id: name` does not exist, then I get the following error with the above query:
`Cannot update 'value' and 'value.bay' at the same time`
The error makes me think that it's not possible to do this in a single query :/

Edit:
I've also tried the following for `$setOnInsert`:

```
$setOnInsert: {
    _id: name,
    value: { ace: true },
}
```

With the thought that maybe possibly I could set another value in the object that is not affected by the field being updated with `$max`

Comment: Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006804/possible-to-do-partial-update-but-complete-document-upsert-in-mongodb
The example in this issue works, but like the poster mentions, not ideal as you need to specify object fields. If there is no other way, I can do it this way.

Comment: No there is no other way https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10711

Comment: Thank you @AlexBlex